# Setting a cookie to expire on a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div on a page using bootstrap navbar-inverse. When the page loads the user will click the close button then set a cookie to expire in 2 days. So next time the user comes to the page and the cookie expires the div would be hidden. Otherwise the div is shown. Appreciate your response.

//here is the div there are other content on the page.

```
<div id="myFooter">
  <div class="navbar-inverse1 navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="close" id="myButton" data-dismiss="navbar">&times;</button>
        <h1 class="text-center">Do Something Here</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content. It's also called placeholder (or filler) text. It's a convenient tool for mock-ups. It helps to outline the visual elements of a document or presentation, so to deliberately render its content nonsensical; it's not genuine, correct, or comprehensible Latin anymore. While lorem ipsum's still resembles classical Latin</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

//here is the script but can't get it to work.

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
    // initially popup click to hide:
       $('.close').click(function() {
          $('#myFooter').hide();
        });
    // Check for the "whenToShowPopup" cookie, if not found then show the popup and save the cookie.
    // The cookie will expire and every 2 days and the popup will show again.
        limit = 5;
        idleTime = 0;
        if ($.cookie('whenToShowPopup') == null) {
          function timerIncrement() {
            idleTime = idleTime + 1;
            if (idleTime > $limit && $.cookie('whenToShowPopup') != 'yes') {
              $('#myFooter').show();
              idleTime = 0;
              console.log('whenToShowPopup', 'idleTime');
          // Create expiring cookie, 2 days from now:
              $.cookie('whenToShowPopup', 'yes', {
                expires: 2,
                path: '/'
              });
          // Show Popup
              $('#myFooter').hide();
              console.log('whenToShowPopup', 'cookie created');
            };
          });
      }); 
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript seems to be missing some curly braces.

Here is the formatted code. (might not solve your logic).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // initially popup click to hide:
  $('.close').click(function() {
    $('#myFooter').hide();
  });
  // Check for the "whenToShowPopup" cookie, if not found then show the popup and save the cookie.
  // The cookie will expire and every 2 days and the popup will show again.
  limit = 5;
  idleTime = 0;
  if ($.cookie('whenToShowPopup') == null) {
    function timerIncrement() {
      idleTime = idleTime + 1;
      if (idleTime > $limit && $.cookie('whenToShowPopup') != 'yes') {
        $('#myFooter').show();
        idleTime = 0;
        console.log('whenToShowPopup', 'idleTime');
        // Create expiring cookie, 2 days from now:
        $.cookie('whenToShowPopup', 'yes', {
          expires: 2,
          path: '/'
        });
        // Show Popup
        $('#myFooter').hide();
        console.log('whenToShowPopup', 'cookie created');
      };
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: The code runs with no error but I am not sure if it is creating the cookie. It did not do any of the console.log.

Comment: console.log the cookie, or even better. (when your app is open) press in chrome, press `ctrl+shift+i`. Go to the application tab and under the storage tab and look under cookies to see if your cookie is there. :)